# Python looping through a list getting list indices error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an list and would like to loop through each row and print the value from column 1. I am getting the error message `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list` What am I missing here?

```
test = [[1,2,4],[3,4,3]]

for currentrow in test:
     print test[currentrow][1]
```

Comment: what makes you think `currentrow` is an index ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to access second element in each of the arrays in the test this what you would do:

```
test = [[1,2,4],[3,4,3]]

for currentrow in test:
    print currentrow[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example, `currentrow` will be a list.

So what you want to do is

```
test = [[1,2,4],[3,4,3]]

for currentrow in test:
    print currentrow[1]
```

will print

```
2
4
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use a for loop in Python, the variable `currentrow` will be assigned the actual object in the list, not the index. So, what you want is the following:

```
test = [[1,2,4],[3,4,3]]

for currentrow in test:
     print currentrow[1]
```

A benefit of this approach is that it's a bit easier to read as well.

If you'd like the index to be available in the loop body, you can use `enumerate`. Here's an example:

```
test = [[1,2,4],[3,4,3]]

for i, currentrow in enumerate(test):
    print "Row {}: {}".format(i, currentrow[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code here is that when you loop through your `test` list, each entry is a list of its own. As such, you're trying to use that entry as an index, which is not possible. Try something like this:

```
for i in range(len(test)):
    print test[i][1]
```

Comment: If you want to use indices, it's recommended to use `enumerate` instead of `range(len(x))` construct. So `for i, lst in enumerate(test)`

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of that. What is the reason for that?

Comment: It's because of how `for` works in python. It is always bit like `foreach` in other languages: it always iterates over an iterator. The `range()` creates a new list (in 2.x, generator in 3.x) of values [1, 2, 3, .., n] and then iterates over that. Other reason is that using `enumerate`, it's much more readable and "more pythonic".

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go) is a good watch if you're interested more.

Comment: @user2242044 What error does it give? I've tried it real quick on the Python interactive console, and it appears to be working.

Comment: @Hamatti Thanks for the link. I'm viewing `enumerate` as just a more abstracted version that I should use since it's also built-in. "Don't reinvent the wheel", right?